# Intellij IDEA - heavy memory usage when testing

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea

I have about 11'000 unit tests, as it looks, IntelliJ stores the tests results in RAM. This cause a very high RAM consumption. As you can see in the attached image. When the heap size is reached, IntelliJ crashes (out of memory). What can I do? To run the packages individually isn't really an option, because it would be very time-consuming. And I already set the heap size to 17'500 MB. I couldn't find a suitable answer on the web.

Edit:

- I already tried this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-148840
- and tried to turn off "show-sql", but it didnt show any effects.

[Memory Usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JS7mX.png)

Comment: May we ask how long this test suite takes to complete?  You can always increase your physical RAM, it is some low value (say 4GB).

Comment: The time is to be found in the image, Tim. 1 h 37 min and some more... Looks like a long time

Comment: About 98 minutes. But with the next commit, we'll reduce it to 32.

Comment: How did you end up in this situation? I mean it must have "worked" for the one who created all those tests...?!

IMHO: you are chasing the wrong problem. Divide an conquer!

Unit tests are supposed to execute in milliseconds. This is some kind of integration test harness. In that case run them on your build server and make sure it has appropriate with memory!

Comment: Well we have about 200 Entities. About 50 tests per entity + relation tests. Now we implemented not-null relations which cause a lot of instancing child elements in @Before of unit tests. This slows down the tests extremly. As next step we split up the big entities.

Comment: I see. When is it that you need to run them all?

Comment: In my opinion, this is just an extreme case. IntelliJ idea's features are  made to work with some reasonable projects and quantities, and you just stepped over that expectation. No blame for idea. In my opinion you better to run your tests in console, maybe it would fit into available memory. Or restructure your tests so you could run it in smaller portions. Anyway, waiting for IntelliJ to fix that is a deadend.

Comment: Well actually I'm not really happy with this solution. But I'm the Junior :) At the moment we have a lot of changes with affect nearly all packages. Starting the packages individually is actually very time-consuming. Because h2 needs about 4-5 min to start.

Comment: @dmitry Yeah, I don't want to blame Intellij for this situation. I just thought there has to be someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Then go talk to the senior devs.

Comment: Open VisualVM and dump heap, then show us what actually occupies it. But if there is a leak, then you should report a bug.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and the problem is that IntelliJ stores console output in memory, so you need to configure your logger and remove all crap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@AutoConfigureMockMvc(print = MockMvcPrint.NONE)` I solved the problem. Spring Boot collected every failed Http-Request and wrote it to the console. And for some reason it isn't cleared after each tests. After hundred of failed tests it reached ten thousands
lines of failed http request, which where printed on each failure and filled up the memory and the console!